# Header and Footer disappearing only in IE7/8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I keep encountering a problem only when we test the updates in IE 7 and 8.

Everything looks perfect on Chrome/Firefox/IE9/10/11/Edge/Whatever but when you view it on 7 or 8 the header and footer change appearance and despite all my attempts, I can't seem to fix the problem.

I've attached screenshots of the header/footer in Chrome/Firefox/The browsers that work and I've also attached the appearance in IE 7/8.

Anyone have an idea what may be a quick fix for this? Or any other ideas? I can't seem to fix it.
Thanks so much in advance!

here are screenshots of what i'm talking about:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd6IJ.jpg

Comment: Can you post the css and html?

Comment: You need to try to recreate this problem and include the html and css applicable. No way to do anything but guess based on the content of the current question.

Comment: We can't provide an answer without code. Please post it directly into the question.

Comment: I've run into this issue before when using HTML5 tags like header and footer. Posting code should help

Comment: i'm adding the code in now!

Comment: If using HTML5, try using something like html5shiv or modernizr so older browsers can interpret those tags.

Comment: how do you post the code? seems a bit long to leave as a comment

Comment: @edrroweye you edit your original message and post the code underneath and make sure you format it correctly with the options that is given  you.

Comment: it says it's too many characters, even in the code box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely used the `<footer>` and `<header>` tag.

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=footer) is a good resource to see what tags are supported in which browsers.

In this case `<footer>` is not supported by `ie8`. The same goes for `<header>`.

Instead, use `<div id="header">` and `<div id="footer">`.

Also, change your css from:

`header {` and `footer {` to `#header {` and `#footer {`

However, you did not post any code so we can never be certain.

Comment: ah yes, this definitely helped with a handful of things! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript library ie7.js is easy to use and will fix all of your IE related problems in very short time. It is more convenient to use this library than trying to fix any possible IE issue on its own.